# Ory / Kratos Login page for Login with Microsoft?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, ory

I am trying to use Ory Kratos and have users login with their existing Microsoft account. After completing the guide at https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/concepts/credentials/openid-connect-oidc-oauth2 I cannot get it to work.

My question is what login url the flow should return? If it is left empty, then a page is displayed saying that this configuration should be set:

```
selfservice:
  flows:
    login:
      ui_url: http://my-app.com/login
```

But I want the user to be presented with Microsoft's login form, and then be redirected back when the user is logged in. I don't want to present a custom login form asking for microsoft credentials.

How should the login flow be configured when using Kratos and Microsoft login flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you mentioned it is mandatory to specify a `ui_url`. So, what you could do try is just hide the default ID, Password and Submit sections of the UI and display only the `Sign in with Microsoft` button.

So the Signin flow becomes more or less like the following:
[image]

That's what I did in my reference implementation that I tried by following the documentation here: https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/guides/sign-in-with-github-google-facebook-linkedin/#microsoft

The link to my reference implementation:
https://github.com/atreya2011/go-kratos-test/tree/microsoft-oidc

Although my reference implementation is in Go, you can adapt it to any other language of your choice!

The config file details are here:
https://github.com/atreya2011/go-kratos-test/tree/microsoft-oidc/config

To try out the reference implementation, you need to have Docker installed and then do the following:

1. Clone the repository locally.
2. Run `docker-compose up --build`
3. Then in your browser, open, `http://localhost:4455/login`

Don't forget to update the config with your `client_id` and `client_secret` that you got from Microsoft!

Hope my answer was helpful :)